# What's difference between get and [] call in Kotlin?

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

I'm making game using Kotlin language + LibGDX library.

Kotlin version: `1.1.2-4`

LibGDX version: `1.9.6`

As official documentation says

```
"[] operation stands for calls to member functions get() and set()."
```

But, when i try to run this line of code:

`body.userData = animations[state[e].currentState]!!.keyFrames[frame]`

I get this error:

`Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;`

However when i change [] to get():

`body.userData = animations[state[e].currentState]!!.keyFrames.get(frame)`

Everything gets ok.

PS: "frame" is angle, converted to Int.

UPD:
I changed my code little bit

```
val animation: Animation = anim[e].animations[state[e].currentState]!!
val tex = animation.keyFrames[frame] // Get exception on this line anyway
body[e].body.userData = tex
```

“e” is entity refrence from Ashley. “body”, “anim”, and “state” are Ashley component mappers.

For those who doesn’t know what LibGDX is here is Animation class
keyFrames here is just a Java Array.

UPD 2:
I noticed that problem occurs only when i use this constructor:

```
Animation(float frameDuration, Array<? extends T> keyFrames)
```

Looks like interoperable problem.

Comment: What is the type of `keyFrames`?

Comment: which LibGDX version you're using ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan 1.9.6

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek <out TextureRegion>

Comment: Your Animation is type of `TextureRegion` ? Is your body is Box2d body ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yes

Comment: Are you sure that error result coming from the same set of test case? I mean `frame` might be different when you test both case. Just my observation as I didn't see obvious problem here. `[]` and `get()`, `set()` are the same.

Comment: @haxpor I tested it 100 times in a loop and get 100 exceptions vs 0 when i changed to get()

Answer (score 0):

Casting error Object can't be cast to `TextureRegion`

```
public operator fun get(index: Int): T
```

Returns the array element at the specified index of `kotlin.Array`.

`T[] keyFrames` is an Arrays of type T in `Animation` class.

---

I declared in this way, I don't have casting error/exception.  :

```
lateinit var ani:Animation<TextureRegion>
ani = Animation(.1f,TextureRegion(Texture("badlogic.jpg")))
val y= ani.keyFrames.get(0)   // -> y is a TextureRegion
```

Replaced with indexing operator

```
val x=ani.keyFrames[0]      // -> x is a TextureRegion
```

Then assign to body userData.

```
val world = World(Vector2(10f,10f),false)
val body = world.createBody(BodyDef())
body.userData = y       //  -> Either you use x or y you always get sprite

var sprite=Sprite(body.userData as TextureRegion?)
```

Comment: I don't actually understand what you're mean. I got exception even in this line "val texture = animations[state[e].currentState]!!.keyFrames[frame]". I don't think that i cast something here.

Comment: what is animations ? Is it arrays of Animation ? and `state[e].currentState` ?

Comment: animations is HashMap<String, Animation<out TextureRegion>>()

Comment: state is component mapper from Ashley. currentState is String, but i don't think this can help so

Comment: I don't think so problem is in above line, may be you're accessing in some other system